# Where to set consensus algorithm in corda?

Tags: corda

- Where to set consensus algorithm in corda? Answer is expecting in a
  technical point of view and if we are working with multiple consensus algorithm then where we switch these algorithms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Corda 3, implementing a custom notary service is still an experimental feature. The APIs for implementing custom notary services may change in the future. Additionally, customising Raft or BFT notaries is not yet fully supported. If you want to write your own Raft notary, you will have to implement a custom database connector (or use a separate database for the notary), and use a custom configuration file.

The first step in implementing a custom notary is to create a notary service class in your CorDapp (i.e. one annotated with `@CordaService`). The Corda node scans for these service classes and initialises them at srart-up. The custom notary service class should provide a constructor taking an `AppServiceHub` and a `PublicKey`:

```
@CordaService
class MyCustomValidatingNotaryService(override val services: AppServiceHub, override val notaryIdentityKey: PublicKey) : TrustedAuthorityNotaryService() {
    override val uniquenessProvider = PersistentUniquenessProvider()

    override fun createServiceFlow(otherPartySession: FlowSession): FlowLogic<Void?> = MyValidatingNotaryFlow(otherPartySession, this)

    override fun start() {}
    override fun stop() {}
}
```

The next step is to write the notary service flow. You are free to copy and modify the existing built-in flows such as `ValidatingNotaryFlow`, `NonValidatingNotaryFlow`, or implement your own from scratch (following the `NotaryFlow.Service` template). Below is an example of a custom flow for a validating notary service:

```
class MyValidatingNotaryFlow(otherSide: FlowSession, service: MyCustomValidatingNotaryService) : NotaryFlow.Service(otherSide, service) {
    /**
     * The received transaction is checked for contract-validity, for which the caller also has to to reveal the whole
     * transaction dependency chain.
     */
    @Suspendable
    override fun receiveAndVerifyTx(): TransactionParts {
        try {
            val stx = receiveTransaction()
            val notary = stx.notary
            checkNotary(notary)
            verifySignatures(stx)
            resolveAndContractVerify(stx)
            val timeWindow: TimeWindow? = if (stx.coreTransaction is WireTransaction) stx.tx.timeWindow else null
            return TransactionParts(stx.id, stx.inputs, timeWindow, notary!!)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw when (e) {
                is TransactionVerificationException,
                is SignatureException -> NotaryInternalException(NotaryError.TransactionInvalid(e))
                else -> e
            }
        }
    }

    @Suspendable
    private fun receiveTransaction(): SignedTransaction {
        return otherSideSession.receive<NotarisationPayload>().unwrap {
            val stx = it.signedTransaction
            validateRequest(NotarisationRequest(stx.inputs, stx.id), it.requestSignature)
            stx
        }
    }

    @Suspendable
    private fun resolveAndContractVerify(stx: SignedTransaction) {
        subFlow(ResolveTransactionsFlow(stx, otherSideSession))
        stx.verify(serviceHub, false)
        customVerify(stx)
    }

    private fun verifySignatures(stx: SignedTransaction) {
        val transactionWithSignatures = stx.resolveTransactionWithSignatures(serviceHub)
        checkSignatures(transactionWithSignatures)
    }

    private fun checkSignatures(tx: TransactionWithSignatures) {
        try {
            tx.verifySignaturesExcept(service.notaryIdentityKey)
        } catch (e: SignatureException) {
            throw NotaryInternalException(NotaryError.TransactionInvalid(e))
        }
    }

    private fun customVerify(stx: SignedTransaction) {
        // Add custom verification logic
    }
}
```

To enable the service, add the following to the node's configuration:

```
notary : {
    validating : true # Set to false if your service is non-validating
    custom : true
}
```